# Casting column value during update operation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table (ABC) which has one column of type uuid (city), now I want to convert it in array of uuid which is _uuid. To achieve this I have created one temporary column(temp_cities) with data type of _uuid.

When I try to update newly created column with exiting one I am getting following error:

> SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: column "temp_cities" is of type uuid[] but expression is of type uuid

Can someone tell me how to cast this thing. I was able to get the solution for datatype text but not for uuid.

Comment: What do you mean by `_uuid` ("underscore uuid")? Is it some custom type in your DB schema?

Comment: @albina: `_uuid` is the internal name for `uuid[]`

Comment: You try to insert a `uuid` value in a `uuid[]` column. Replace `your_value` of type `uuid` by `array[your_value]` which will be of type `uuid[]`